# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация

В каком случае между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире, а в каком - не ставится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они являются существительными и второе определяет качество первого. Проще говоря, если между этими словами можно поставить союз "это".
Пример: *Москва - столица, фрегат - корабль*.
Тире не ставится, если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит отрицательная частица "не".
Пример: *Работа не волк, курица не птица*.

Answer (score 0):

Тире ставится: если и подлежащее и сказуемое выражены сущ. Именительного падежа; инфинитивами; числительными именительного падежа. Подлежащее инфинитив, а сказуемое сущ. Именительного падежа и наоборот. Подлежащее числительное, а сказуемое - сущ. Именительного падежа и наоборот. Примеры: Жить - Родине служить. Трижды три - девять. Высота башни - три метра. Учить - благородное занятие.
Перед словами вот, это, значит.
Не ставится: перед вводными словами, словом есть и частицей не. Примеры: Надо - значит надо. Сказки есть душа народа. Гусь, несомненно, важная птица.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с предыдущими ответами, но не ставится тире еще и перед наречиями, союзами, несмотря на то, что подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именами существительными: Май уже последний месяц весны; Платина тоже драгоценный металл.

Answer (score 0):

"У школьников коренных народностей антропометрические данные имеют меньшие размеры (468,23±29,83 мм - у мальчиков и 464,51±21,96 мм - у девочек"). Нужно ли ставить тире в части предложения, взятой в скобки?

Comment: Я бы здесь двоеточие поставила.